# Changing size of db column from varchar50 to varchar255

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Inside `microsoft sql server` database I have table `User` with column `Password`. `Password` is of type `varchar(50)` and I want to change to `varchar(255)`.

I tried using `microsoft sql server management studio` and using design view I tried manually to change 50 to 255 but on saving that action I'm getting alert

> Following tables will be saved to your database. Do you want to continue?

```
User
xx
xx
xx
```

On chosing yes I'm waiting for whole min with mouse cursor busy and I'm getting back

> Errors were encountered during the save process. Some database objects were not saved.
>   User table, Unable to delete relationship FK.....
>   Timeout expired.

I'm confused since I'm not changing anything but this lenght of Password column.

Is there any simple way to complete this simple operation, change `varchar(50)` to `varchar(255)`

Comment: This suggests others users might still be logged in or otherwise using the database http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic999886-149-1.aspx

Answer (score 3):

When you use the designer to make changes, behind the scenes SSMS generates a huge script that creates a new temporary table, dumps all the data from the old one into the temporary one, deletes the old table and then renames the temporary table back to the name of the original name. It also is smart enough to drop foreign keys, constraints, etc. and then tries to put them all back later. Depending on the complexity of the table the script can be hundreds or thousands of lines long.

Instead, since you're really just asking for a little more space in your column which is keeping the same underlying data type, you could directly alter the data type of the column with a simple two-liner:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[User]
    ALTER COLUMN [Password] varchar(255) NOT NULL
GO
```

(Adjust the script according to whether the column is nullable, has defaults, etc.)

Of course you should have a backup of the database that table is in before you do any of this. You may also need to drop existing connections to the database. It could be that the script is waiting for exclusive access to the table before it does any work.

Comment: Trid this, over 3min of execution this script and counting.

Comment: Do you have anything else running that might have a lock on the table?

Comment: If an interruption of service isn't an issue, you could take the database offline (which will disconnect anybody still accessing it), make the change, and then bring it back up. But I have no idea what your environment is like (do you have after-hours downtime or are you running a 24/7 100%-uptime-required server, in a replicated/clustered environment, etc), so that could be a terrible idea.